# Hypothesis testing: difference between proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, t-test, proportion

I am investigating staff inequality between genders and ethnicities in an institution. I have data on contract types (permanent or fixed term) and pay grades for almost all employees. I want to test the hypothesis that there is no inequality across genders and ethnicities in contract types or pay grades.

For example, I have that 592/1972 white people are on a fixed term contract, while 57/114 black or minority ethnicity are on a fixed term contract. Which statistical test to use to test the hypothesis that there is no significant difference?

I was thinking of using the t-test, however the dependent variable is not continuous (it is proportions). I then thought about the two-proportion z test but each of my populations are not at least 10 times as big as its sample (at least for the gender case). I don't think categorical data analysis would help either because I still need to incorporate the fact that I have different sizes of populations? Which test then best matches the assumptions?

Moreover, since I am interested in generalising only to the institution itself, I can say I have the whole population in my data (non-responses were minor), how does that help/not help the analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you truly have the whole population of interest, there's no need for a hypothesis test at all. The point of hypothesis tests are to make inferences about populations. If you *have* the population you don't need to infer its characteristics from a sample ... you simply look at it. The null is either true or false and you can say which is true (for certain).

(If you have a large fraction of the population of interest, for some tests you have to worry about finite sample effects.)

To compare two proportions, some commonly used tests include the two-proportions Z-test, the chi-square test and Fishers exact test.

Fisher's exact test conditions on both margins in the 2x2 table (and for that matter, the chi-square is also useable in that situation). So by conditioning on both margins, the finite sample issue should be a non-issue -- it's taken care of by the conditioning.

Comment: I disagree that "If you truly have the whole population of interest, there's no need for a hypothesis test at all" because question is not if there is the same proportion or black or white people with some kind of contract. The question here is whether white and black people have the same probability of getting that kind of contract, and to know that you do need hypothesis test - the ones you describe in the last paragraphs of your answer.

Comment: @Pere If you have the whole population of interest, the probability of observing a white person with some kind of contract is $\pi_w=\frac{\text{number of white people in that population with that contract}}{\text{Number of white people in that population}}$ and similarly, $\pi_b=\frac{\text{number of black people in that population with that contract}}{\text{Number of black people in that population}}$. If those two ratios are different, the population parameters are different. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... If you think the probability is not that ratio, *you don't have the whole population of interest*.

Comment: I think I haven't properly worded my comment or properly understood the remarks in your answer. I agree that if we have the whole population of interest, we don't need inference since we can get the proportion by just counting. The issue here is that all employees in the institution is not the whole population of interest, because they are instances from a random distribution, and our population of interest consists on all possible instances of such distribution, not all actual employees in the institution. That is, @Keksainis doesn't have the whole population of interest.

Comment: @Pere Yes, it sounds like we agree -- when we say we "have the population" it's important to be clear about whether we simply have "a population" rather than "the population of interest" (the one we want to make the inferences about). That was the reason I specified the first sentence of my answer the way I did. When people claim to have the population of interest -- but are then confronted with the plain fact that  they can just calculate the population parameters -- they often realize the population of interest is not the population they have a census of.

Answer (score 3):

A 2x2 [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) ought to suffice. When I plug your numbers into a chi-squared calculator I see a statistically significant difference:

http://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/chi-squared.html#!592/1972;57/114@95

In the above calculation Sample 2 corresponds to the minority group. I.e. they are on a fixed-term contract more often than the white group.

(Disclosure: that's my web page and I wrote the calculator.)